# Does SQL have an implies (->) relational operator

Tags: sql, operators, logic

I want to express the condition (in a where clause) where a value in one column mandates a condition must be met in another column. This is a logical implies (→) relation and is equivalent to "not A or B" (¬A∨B).

Is there an existing SQL operator or function for that? I fear the `(not(A) or B)` expression may confuse future maintainers of my code who do not have a CS background.

Comment: I disagree.  The parenthetical representation you posted is perfectly clear.

Comment: Standard SQL doesn't have such an operator! What is really confusing about (not(A) or B)?

Comment: If you think it is confusing, wrap it in a user defined function.

Comment: Leave a comment for the poor uneducated fool who comes after you

Comment: I guess I'll use comments for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such operator. Define such a function or use comments.